# Not getting selection from PDFView

Tags: swift, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I see somewhere this code for highlight selected text in pdf document:

```
let select = pdfView.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()
    //assuming for single-page pdf.
    guard let page = select?.first?.pages.first else { return }

    select?.forEach({ selection in
        let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: select.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
        highlight.endLineStyle = .square
        highlight.color = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        page.addAnnotation(highlight)
    })
```

for me ,

let select = pdfView.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()

is always giving nil. where to put this code. I putting it in Gesture Recogniser Delegate methods.

Also it seems adding multiple annotation on page. Do we get single highlight annotation per selection on a page?